# Matrix norm proof

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given is $\left | \left | A \right | \right |_{2} =\left ( \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}^{2} \right )^\frac{1}{2}$ for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show that this defines a matrix norm.

I remember i've been reading something about Frobenius norm, but it was defined in a different way, if i am not wrong as $\left | \left | A \right | \right |_{2}=\sqrt{tr(A^{t}A)}$, where $A^{t}$ was the transposed matrix $A$.

I am sorry about the trivial question, but do i have to prove here that the given norm is Frobenius norm?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right. In fact if $A=(a_{ij})$ then $A^t=(b_{ij})$ where $b_{ij}=a_{ji}$ so if $C=(c_{ij})=A^tA$ then
$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}a_{kj}$$
hence
$$\operatorname{tr}(A^tA)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}^2$$
Now to prove the given expression defines a norm you can *for example* prove that the map
$$\varphi:\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)\times \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)\rightarrow \Bbb R,\quad (A,B)\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(A^tB)$$
is an inner product and $||.||_2$ is the euclidean norm associated to this inner product.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed the Frobenius norm.  So, if you've established that the Frobenius norm is indeed a matrix norm, it is sufficient to show that this is that, which is a norm.

In order to show that they are the same, note the following:

The $ith$ diagonal entry of $A^TA$ is given by
$$
b_{ii}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}^2
$$
So that
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A^TA) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}^2
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, i was a little confused by the notation in my problem, but now is clear what i have to do. :) Have a nice day!